# Object to dictonary to use get() python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm having some issues with a column in my csv that the type is an 'object', but it's should be an dict series (a dict for which row).

The point is to make which row as a dict to use get('id') on the key to return the id's values for which row in the 'Conta' column.

Thats the way it's as 'object' column:

```
| Conta                                        |
| ---------------------------------------------|
| {'name':'joe','id':'4347176000574713087'}    |
| {'name':'mary','id':'4347176000115055151'}   |
| {'name':'fred','id':'4347176000574610147'}   |
| {'name':'Marcos','id':'4347176000555566806'} |
| {'name':'marcos','id':'4347176000536834310'} |
```

Thats the way it's should be in the end

```
| Conta               |
| ------------------- |
| 4347176000574713087 |
| 4347176000115055151 |
| 4347176000574610147 |
| 4347176000555566806 |
| 4347176000536834310 |
```

I tried to use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('csv/Modulo_CS.csv')
df['Conta'] = df['Conta'].to_dict()
df['Conta'] = [x.get('id', 0) for x in df['Conta']]
#return: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I also tried to use ast.literal_eval() but it dosen't work as well

```
import ast
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('csv/Modulo_CS.csv')
df = df[['Conta','ID_CS']]
df['Conta'] = df['Conta'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
#return: ValueError: malformed node or string: nan
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing the following line:

```
df['Conta'] = df['Conta'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

If it's being correctly detected as a dictionary then:

```
df['Conta'] = df['Conta].map(lambda x: x['id'])
```

If each row is a string:

```
df['Conta'] = df['Conta'].map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)['id'])
```

However, if you are getting a malformed node or json error. Consider first using `str` and then `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
df['Conta'] = df['Conta'].map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(str(x))['id'])
```

Comment: Same error as before "ValueError: malformed node or string: nan" @celius-stingher

Comment: Please try with the edited version?

Comment: Something could be wrong with your example. Even creating an excel and copy pasting the dictionary as rows works fine.

Comment: I think that the problem is there some nulls values on my column, I will try to deal with it as json also